# Quick way to check 2 lists are the same c#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Suppose there are these two strongly typed lists:

List 1 : existingitems

ID, Name, Cat

1, ABC, C
2, BCD, D

3, NNN, F

List 2 : newitems

ID, Name, Cat
9, ABC, C
15, BCD, D
12, NNN, F

Basically, I want to check that the Name and Cat values are the same in both lists. If the two lists are identical on these two columns, return true, otherwise false.

I'd tried a few variations mostly around the below but always seems to return true, even is the newitems list has a new row, which I would expect to return false.

```
newitems.Any(x1 => existingitems.All(x2 => (x1.Name== x2.Name) && (x1.Cat== x2.Cat)));
```

Comment: why would you expect to return **false** ? your Name and Cat values are the same in two list.

Comment: Do the items need to be in the same order, or not?

Comment: @Selman22 my comment about returning false would be if the New list has a row which isn't in the existing. otherwise, return true. Solved now anyway.

Comment: The requirements about what should be understand as being "the same in both lists" are indeed somewhat unclear. Hence the varying solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is probably the cleanest and simplest solution for you.

```
var list1Subset = list1.Select(i => new {i.Name, i.Cat});
var list2Subset = list2.Select(i => new {i.Name, i.Cat});

bool equal = list1Subset.SequenceEqual(list2Subset);
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest ones are the best. I didn't even think of going down this route, does the job. Thanks

Comment: @Andy Note that this solution, unlike every single other solution, requires the items in each list to be in the same order, which is why it can be simpler.  If the items are *not* in the same order, this will return `false`.  It is unclear if that is desirable or not.

Comment: This is actually fine as the lists are in a particular order.

Comment: @Servy is correct. I assumed (hopefully correctly) that order mattered but it was not specified.

Comment: @Andy what if they aren't in the same order?

Comment: The way that these lists are being used in the application means that they will be in the same order.

Comment: To clarify, basically the existing list is populated already and this populates a webpage. this page is then saved into another table, called new. However, items can be added to this new list on the page. I'm just trying to detect if there is anything new.

Comment: Sounds awful and it is. Just what i've inherited and have to sort very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this efficiently with a `HashSet` and custom comparer:

```
public class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return (x.Cat == y.Cat) && (x.Name == y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        return (obj.Cat.GetHashCode() * 17) + (obj.Name.GetHashCode() * 17);
    }
}

public bool AreEqual(IEnumerable<T> set1, IEnumerable<T> set2, 
    IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
{
    // Handle cheapest cases
    if (set1 == null && set2 == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (set1 == null && set2 != null
        || set1 != null && set2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (object.ReferenceEquals(set1, set2))
    {
        return true;
    }

    var hashSet1 = new HashSet<T>(set1, equalityComparer);
    var hashSet2 = new HashSet<T>(set2, equalityComparer);

    // More easy cases
    if (hashSet1.Count != hashSet2.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (set1.Any(i => !hashSet2.Contains(i))
        || set2.Any(i => !hashSet1.Contains(i)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: hashSet1.Count != hashSet2.Count What if there was items with the same Name and Cat in one IEnumerable and only one in another?

Comment: @DanielGrankin excellent point, but it wasn't part of the spec as to whether or not the sets had repeated/duplicate values.

Comment: I think if there isn't allowed to disregard duplicates I don't have to disregard it and make more general solution. Just my opinion:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var areEqual = !existingitems.Select(x => new { x.Name, x, Cat })
                       .Except(newItems.Select(x => new { x.Name, x, Cat }))
                       .Any() 
             && !newItems.Select(x => new { x.Name, x, Cat })
                       .Except(existingitems.Select(x => new { x.Name, x, Cat }))
                       .Any();
```

or

```
var areEqual
     = newItems.Select(x => new { x.Name, x, Cat })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
               .ThenBy(x => x.Cat)
               .SequanceEquals(existingitems.Select(x => new { x.Name, x, Cat })
                                       .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                                       .ThenBy(x => x.Cat));
```

Answer (score -1):

We can first define a method to determine if two sequences are equal sets:

```
public static bool SetEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first
    , IEnumerable<T> second
    , IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return new HashSet<T>(second).SetEquals(first);
}
```

Then we can filter out the fields that you want and perform the set equality on that projection:

```
var areEqual = list1.Select(item => new{item.Name, item.Cat})
    .SetEquals(list2.Select(item => new{item.Name, item.Cat}));
```

Comment: You're iterating each source sequence twice.

Comment: @DanielGrankin No I'm not.  I iterate the second sequence exactly once, and the first sequence either partially, or at most, once fully, depending on whether short circuiting happens or not.  Neither sequence is ever iterated twice.

Comment: @Servy Seems to me that there are itterations on each Select, on HashSet creating and on invoking .SetEquals(first).

Comment: @DanielGrankin `Select` will iterate the source sequence, creating an intermediate sequence, which is then iterated through the `HashSet` constructor.  `SetEquals` then iterates the *other* sequence while accessing data from the in-memory collection.  None of this involves the *source sequence* being iterated multiple times.  Your comment implies that you're not really familiar with the underlying mechanisms at play here; it's not really possible to explain in more detail in comments, the best I can say is that you should go do some more research into LINQ and sequences.

Comment: @Servy It doesn't reduce count of itterations anyway if you use other intermidiate sequences, there are only one benefit if sequence contains a lot of duplicates BUT the first sequence can contain more duplicates than the second and HashSet hide this, HashSet will contain only one item for duplicates and your approach will not work correctly. I either itterated intermidiate sequences. the best I can say is that you should go do some more research into Collections.

Comment: @Servy The same question that I asked David Haney. What if there was items with the same Name and Cat in one IEnumerable and only one in another?

Comment: @DanielGrankin Clearly more than one iteration of "something" happens in the solution.  That's not at all what the issue is however.  The question is how many times *the source sequence* is iterated.  The original data source is iterated no more than once.  Whether other sequences/collections are iterated is an entirely different matter.  Iterating the source sequence more than once makes a solution *incorrect*.  Iterating multiple intermediate collections isn't a problem at all, doesn't impact correctness, and at worst, *might* affect performance, although that won't be an issue here.